# Trying to capture Android web traffic using Fiddler - "webpage is not available"

Tags: android, web, proxy, fiddler

I've been trying to setup a proxy connection with my Nexus 5 using this tutorial - [Capture Android Mobile Web Traffic With Fiddler](http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler)

My PC and my Nexus are both connected to my personal wifi.

No matter where do I browse to I'm getting an error - "The webpage is not available".

Comment: Is your "personal wifi" configured to allow wireless-to-wireless connections? Some routers disable this by default. On your Android device, *without* setting the proxy, what happens if you navigate to `http://fiddlerpcIP:8888/`?

Comment: How can I check that configuration? When trying to connect without setting the proxy it says, again, "the webpage is not available".

Comment: If you cannot reach http://fiddlerpcIP:8888/ from the device it means you either didn't enable Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections > Allow Remote (then restart), or your PC firewall is blocking access, or you are using the wrong IP address, or your router is configured not to allow wireless client to wireless client access. What wifi router are you using?